# GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort SIGABRT crash, reboot the device can fix this issue, however I want to find the root cause

Tags: iphone, crash

The same issue as the following thread, reboot the device can fix this issue, however I want to find the root cause, user upgrades our app, we can't expect them to reoot the device to use it normally.

It will always occur by the following steps.

1. User launch app with version 1.1.
2. User put app into background (still running).
3. User upgrade app to new version 1.2.
4. User click app icon, app crash during startup.

Any idea or discussion will be apprecicated, thanks in advance.

[GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort SIGABRT in UIApplicationMain Before App Delegate Gets to Run Any Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589631/gsregisterpurplenamedport-sigabrt-in-uiapplicationmain-before-app-delegate-gets)

Answer (score 0):

App is crashed before new version app installed, some system clean action hasn't been done.