# UITableView crashing with comma and space in String of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

If i have a string like "**`Help, Support and More`**" in an `NSArray` which is content of an `UITableView` it crashes on startup. If i remove the whitespace after "**`,`**" there is no Problem.

Is there any solution for this?

This **crashes**:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Help, Support and More";
```

This **works**:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Help,Support and More";
```

Here is more code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSLog(@"%@", [[sportstypes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] title]);
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Tes t:, ,,,,,";
    //cell.textLabel.text = @"Blubber";

    return cell;
}
```

FIX: [Xcode 4.6.2 app crashes on every second run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113036/xcode-4-6-2-crash-when-run-of-a-second-time)
Thanks to ice_2

Comment: Can you please provide us with the code ? On which line it is crashing?

Comment: I added some code above.

Comment: what? Never.Show us your datasource code

Comment: What does the crash error say?

Comment: Is this code-snippet more helpful?

Comment: enough .Please add error log.Nothing wrong in code till now

Comment: There is no error log or any error, only "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: It only dies every second "Run"...really strange!

Comment: in my this code works, with any string

Comment: nothing is shown in the console debugger??

Comment: I have tested your @"Help, Support and More" but no crash. also try removing the white space. can you show me the log of that crash? May be there is any special character not white space but you can not detect it.

If you check the character of that white space will get that special character and will modify the code correctly.

Comment: I tried some more, every second run of the app with xcode crashes on start when the white space is present. I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: It also crashes without any whitespaces

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113036/xcode-4-6-2-crash-when-run-of-a-second-time or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113848/ios-app-crashing-every-other-launch-cant-find-error

Comment: How many warnings are you ignoring? you said, you dont use ARC. your cell is leaking. and probably a lot more objects in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on every second launch.
Please open the menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, select Run YouAppName.app on the left, tab Info. Then choose GDB instead of LLDB in debugger field.

Seems to be a combination of OS X 10.8.4 and LLDB. As kenster says, switching to GDB makes the problem go away.

Comment: This is all i got from GDB:GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824) (Wed Feb  6 22:51:23 UTC 2013)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 4202.
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: After this the app is dead.

Comment: what osx version you have?

Comment: i updated this morning to 10.8.4. I tried something, reverted it back and now the crash is no more reproduceable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong. Because your code is correct no problem in your code and second thing you  can put any special character in double quot **" "**. It wont create any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of memory issue.Make sure the array is not deallocated or removed anywhere.Enable zombie and run it so that you can recieve some log in the debugger console

Issue may be in this line

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[sportstypes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] title]);
```

comment it and execute and see for yourself what happens

Comment: I do not use ARC. Could this be the problem, that i have a hugh amount of zombies around?

Comment: does the word "Zombie" sound like it is a good idea to collect them?

Comment: I do not collect them, but my question was if it could be the main problem that i do not use ARC?

Comment: did you comment the line in the answer and execute?Still it shows the crash?