# xcode ios crashing intermittently

Tags: crash, ios7, xcode5

I had my xcode working fine,

I updated my phone to iOS 7 and downloaded the latest xcode.

Now if I create an empty app, then run it on simulator,

the app will crash intermittently,
nothing else added... so it will run some times, then will crash on start up,

No error log, only

> lldb

and on main.m I see:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

What is the problem?

thanks!

Comment: try running simulator separately and  "reset content and settings" (in "iOS Simulator" menu of simulator)

Comment: Have you enabled "All exception" breakpoint?

Comment: May be problem in your Xcode is not updated. See more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113036/xcode-4-6-2-app-crashes-on-every-second-run/17126880?noredirect=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS app crashing every other launch, can't find error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113848/ios-app-crashing-every-other-launch-cant-find-error)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete the app from the simulator, clean project, restart Xcode and rerun it.

If that doesn't work try to reinstall it again.