# Can't run app in simulator :: XCODE 5

Tags: ios7, xcode5

May because its DP and they will fix it, but for time being anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

For me only reboot is solving the issue. I could have done this but its becoming very frequent. [image]

It works fine when running in device. Any help appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162257/xcode-ios-crashing-intermittently/17177759#17177759 Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Michael D suggested, I got an instant answer from Dev forum.

Here is the answer:

> Delete the app from simulator or reset the simulator.

Later I got Similar issue in iPhone too. Deleting the app from iPhone will solve that issue also.

This works.

Comment: I'm having this too and the solution helps, but the next time I run my app I get the same error again. So this only works once for me.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I think this is Xcode bug some what similar to the simulator crash issue in Xcode 4.6.2 that was fixed in Xcode 4.6.3

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug of xcode5 preview 1, if you modified xib with xcode5, it will result app failed install in simulator.you can revert xib changes and run again.

Comment: Its an old thread. Issue solved. Please find the answer above. Thanks for your concern.