# Xcode5 Facing strange issue with testing app iOS Simulator failed to install the application

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

Hi i facing strange issue with running `Xcode5` latest release version `Mountain Lion mac with 10.8.5` update.

From yesterday i can not run application in simulator. I got the Error Message while running app like.

[image]

I read some related issue in Stack Overflow and also doing this Following Step for fix this but still facing same issue.

> - I am trying to reset Content and setting simulator
> - Remove all Build from Derive data folder.
> - Restart mac system Many time after doing above two step.
> - From simulator Folder remove all Project Build

[image]

i Chinking this follow related question

[Can't run app in simulator :: XCODE 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187545/cant-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-5)

[Xcode 5 - "iOS Simulator failed to install application" every time I switch simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746093/xcode-5-ios-simulator-failed-to-install-application-every-time-i-switch-simu)

While i am trying to Run Project in simulator i got above Error and simulator contain Only Black Screen i can't see default Application or install Application.

For Testing i just create New single view project in Xcode5 and try to run also i got the same error. please guide me and help me to fixing this issue.

Comment: are you in Xcode5 demo version?

Comment: Nope upadte from App store this is release version or Xcode5

Comment: make a backup of your app and upgrade it to ios7 and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lost of search and reset everything in My issue just **reset Content and setting simulator** is not useful. Because i have not seen anything in `simulator`. can't access Home screen so got No luck then **Remove** each `Xcode` related file like:-

> ~/Library/Application Support/**Xcode**
>
> ~/Library/**iPhone Simulator**
>
> ~/application->move to trash **Xcode**
>
> Clean and Empty Trash

Then i am going to again Install `Xcode` from `Appstore` and now lonching again and run the Test app that working Fine now.