# Simulator fails to open

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I always getting this error whenever i runs iOS 6 series simulators.  I tried lot of steps for this problem. i.e., 1. deleting Derived Data, Creating a new project ..

[Notification center label http://imageshack.com/a/img836/3808/adat.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img836/3808/adat.png)

if anyone tell me the solution for this.

Comment: close the simulator and xcode - run the program again or else try below answer - if you want to keep your old data

Comment: i also tried Reset option but it's not working

Comment: run any template program run it - see everything is fine or else last option you try is restart (its weired/silly) but works for me

Comment: which version of code are you using

Comment: do you have which one lion or Mavericks

Comment: or it comes phonegap based application

Comment: i am using lion and native based application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not provided more details i post answer in guessing from you question

refer below link it more helpful.

[IOS simulator failed to install application? in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221297/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-application-in-xcode-5)

[iOS Simulator failed to install the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932750/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application)

https://discussions.apple.com/message/24468440#24468440

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that your application's plist settings are not changed .. if you try to do anything which in not approved by the iOS this messege is shown quite often . Then please reset the settings and contents of iOS Simulator. Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset iOS 6.1 simulator from menu "iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...",

then run your app in XCode

Comment: It never hurst to run Clean on your project too.